# Running hardware with only 32bit drivers in 64bit windows

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, virtualization, 32-bit

Recently we had to upgrade a system to handle added HD IP cameras. This upgrade involved an entirely new computer build with the exception of a rather pricey Geovision DVR (PCI/GV1480 series). Apparently while these cards do support Windows 7, they do not support Windows 7 x64.

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place here trying to figure out how we can remedy this, is there a virtualization solution that will allow devices with driver issues to passthru to the Guest OS? I was thinking XPMode may work for this solution however I am unsure if it runs 32bit or 64bit and if it'll allow driver-issue devices to pass to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Best Regards,
Howard

Comment: Why can't you use a 32-bit version of Windows?

Comment: How do the cameras connect? USB? PCI?

Comment: @kotekzot The system has 8gb of ram.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The cameras connect to the PCI card via serial cables which expand into several RCA cables.

Comment: XPMode is 32-bit, but I don't think it can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck using VMware Player to pass my friend's camcorder (which lacks 64-bit drivers) from a 64-bit host to a 32-bit VM.  In that case, the device was connected via USB.  VMware also supports pass-through of SCSI devices, but I don't think that will work for your PCI DVR card.